# Mosca Mqtt Broker read published message

Tags: node.js, mqtt, mosca

Hello I am using mosca mqtt broker I want to read the message that a client publish to a topic.

Is there any way to do that?

In published event I log the packet.payload and it prints only clientid and topic.

```
server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
    console.log('Published', packet.payload);
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use the callback "on `published` " to log the published message either in a file or maybe in your database for accessing whenever you need it, like:

```
server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
    // Do what you want with your message here
    var msg = packet.payload.toString('utf8');
});
```

**Be careful of internal messages though. this callback does not filter for you so you have to do it yourself.**

Refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38296318/4242450)

Answer (score 0):

```
server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
    console.log('Published: ', packet.payload.toString('utf8'));
});
```

Comment: You can make this answer more useful by adding text explaining what this code does and how it solves the problem.  Answers with nothing but raw code aren't as helpful as answers that explain the code.